# Can't access DOM via functions in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a Chrome extension that highlights certain words that were entered in extension's textfield

For example: I enter "web" in extension's area, press the button.  On active tab all "web" words are should be highlighted.

I've found a nice [web-page](http://www.nsftools.com/misc/SearchAndHighlight.htm)that has all the functions I need.

In my code, when I try to use them in my Extension, nothing works.

**manifest file**

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "Word search & highlight",
"version": "1.0",

"icons": {
    "16": "16x16.png",
    "32": "32x32.png",
    "48": "48x48.png",
    "128": "128x128.png"
 },
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": [ "*://*/*" ],
  "js": [ "popup.js"],
  "run_at": "document_end"
 }
],

"permissions": [
"tabs", "activeTab"
],


"browser_action": {
   "default_title": "Start searching",
    "default_icon": "48x48.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
 }
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="searchtextfield"><br>
<input id="btn_save" value="Save" type="button">
<input id="btn_search" value="Search" type="button"><br>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's `popup.js` file: it's too long, so I made a pastebin document:

http://pastebin.com/g5ZenE48

I can't get innerHTML of webpage from these functions and I don't really understand how to make this all work.

Comment: You're approaching this in the wrong way. Code running in the popup context can't act as a content script. I suggest you look into [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) as you'll need to implement the following workflow: 1) user enters text in the popup. 2) popup sends message to content script. 3) content script handles DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sean-adams is correct, your browser action (popup.html) cannot communicate directly with your content script (popup.js). You can think of a content script as being an addition to whatever page the user is visiting, whereas the browser action is directly integrated as part of your chrome extension.

So, you will indeed need to use message passing to communicate. It's simple though. First, I recommend renaming your browser action popup to something like `browser_popup.html`. I'll use a stripped down example for brevity:

```
//browser_popup.html
<input type="button" id="my_button" value="Click Me">
<script src='browser_popup.js'></script>
```

You'll also want another file `browser_popup.js` for handling events.

```
//browser_popup.js
var button = document.querySelector('#my_button');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Send message to active tab
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, 'button_clicked');
  });
});
```

In your content script (let's call it content.js) you need to listen for the message:

```
//content.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
  if (message == 'button_clicked') {
    // code to modify page...
  }
});
```